# ItemContainer style with nested ItemControls won't bind correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

A summary of what I'm trying to do:

1. I have a list of shapes
2. All shapes have a list of blocks
3. I want to draw all blocks in a canvas and bind their position.

But the problem right now is that even if it draw my blocks it don't bind the position correctly and they always show up at (0,0).

Here is how it look right now with a nested ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Shapes}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="Aqua" Width="250" Height="400"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Blocks}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Fill="Black" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

So what am I doing wrong or is it bad to do nested ItemControls?

Comment: I suspect it binds fine. Problem is in what you think should happen. Direct child of outer `ItemsControl`, one with `Canvas`, is `ContentPresenter` with inner `ItemsControl` which children will have position set. Position will work only on direct children of `Canvas` so, in your case, `ContentPresenter` of outer `ItemsControl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a RenderTransform instead of the Canvas Left and Top

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Fill="Black">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="{Binding X}" Y="{Binding Y}" />
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: There is one problem with this solution, that even if I create many blocks with same position they won't stack. Instead they will line up vertically. Wonder if you (or anyone) have any idea why.

Comment: You could try putting the Rectangle inside a secondary Canvas. Also, you didn't remove the Canvas panel template did you? The panel is required to be a Canvas to work correctly.

Comment: Oh, I added another canvas to the second ItemsControl and made it transparent. Don't know why I didn't think about. Thanks again!